# should_not_receive doesn't fail for Class method

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I'm not quite sure why but my Sinatra rspec tests don't fail properly when they should.  Here's part of my Rspec:

```
context "invalid params" do
        before do
            @params = {}
        end
        it "does not call the Count model" do
            Count.should_not_receive(:increment)
            post '/counts' , @params
        end
end
```

It's not failing though.  However if I switch the should_not_receive line to:

```
Count.should_receive(:increment).exactly(2).times
```

It responds with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Count.should_receive(:increment).exactly(2).times
   (<Count (class)>).increment(any args)
       expected: 2 times
       received: 1 time
```

So why does the first test not fail if it's being called once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing puts last_response.body and last_response.status it turns out that Sinatra is raising an exception and returning a 500 status.

The reason for this after further debugging was that the Rack environment was set to development and not test. Sinatra's documentation says you should be able to put

```
set :environment, :test
```

at the top of your spec file, but that actually doesn't work.  The solution is to add the following line at the very beginning of your spec file before you start requiring any files:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
```

That's it!